# Change color of string between two | symbols

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can we change color of string between two `|` symbols in the given string:

Here is the prototype:

```js
const string = "Starting |this should be colored| there may be more |colored too|";

let result; // save spans here 
result = string; // remove this 

const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.innerHTML = result;
```

```css
.colored { color: #1e00e3; }
```

```html
<div id ="container"></div>
```

Edit: It's not that basic you should select both the string with and without | symbols because we want only the string not the symbols...

Comment: basic regular expression with replace.

Comment: @epascarello well he can also use split and by the array place (all the odds) color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using
[String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
const string = "Starting |this should be colored| there may be more |colored too|";
const result = string.replace(/\|\b([^|]+)\b\|/g, `<span class="colored">$1</span>`);

const container = document.querySelector("#container");
container.innerHTML = result;
```

```css
.colored { color: #1e00e3; }
```

```html
<div id ="container"></div>
```

Or also by using a function:

```js
string.replace(/\|\b([^|]+)\b\|/g, (fullMatch, group1) => {
  return `<span class="colored">${group1}</span>`
});
```

And here's a [Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/4W7vZp/1) to the regular expression from the example above.

Another example:

Comment: I'm wasting my time on what makes me what I am... Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 0):

[Basic regular expression](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5C%7C%28%5B%5E%7C%5D%2B%29%5C%7C%2Fg) with [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
const string = "Starting |this should be colored| there may be more |colored too|";

const result = string.replace(/\|([^|]+)\|/g, '<span class="colored">$1</span>');

const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.innerHTML = result;
```

```css
.colored {
  color: #1e00e3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Note: It works fine with basic text like that is given. Add in complexities like HTML markup and this solution would not work.